# False "Map keys must be unique" error for k8s values.yaml on VS code

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am using VS Code to develop a helm chart. I have installed the [YAML extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml).

It is common for charts to contain snippets like this:

```yaml
 annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "internal-nginx"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

The snippet above defines two annotations that have the same key, which is totally valid in k8s world, but the editor is complaining about the duplicated keys:

```json
[{
    "resource": "/home/junowong/Sentry/uet-tracker-15.0.0/configuration.yaml",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Map keys must be unique",
    "source": "YAML",
    "startLineNumber": 95,
    "startColumn": 15,
    "endLineNumber": 95,
    "endColumn": 58
}]
```

How do I turn off this error message on repo/folder/file level?

Answer (score 0):

You should never use duplicate annotations on Kubernetes objects. This will cause undefined behaviour that will be very difficult to debug.

I would suggest instead of turning off the linting rules, you should remove the duplicate annotation.

### Understanding Annotations

Annotations are not validated by `Kubernetes API` because they are processed by external entities. This means there is a high chance you can misconfigure annotations and they will ***by design*** pass transparently through the Kubernetes API server to the external object controller.

They will be processed by this controller instead. In your case it is the `Nginx Ingress Controller`. The ingress controller will either:

1. Tell you to remove the duplicate entry.
2. Misbehave without you knowing what is the problem.

The `labels` however, which are also key/value pairs are a `Kubernetes API` element and they are validated by the API server. They are processed by the API server as well. This is what separates them, functionally, from `annotations`.

Bottom line, YOU SHOULD NOT USE DUPLICATE ANNOTATIONS.